# How can I flow type chained functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, flowtype

I am trying to create basic `flow-typed` definition for `firebase-functions` module.

Example usecase of this module is following:

```
// @flow
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import create from './tasks/create'

const { firestore } = functions

exports.createCharacter = firestore
  .document('characters/{characterID}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => create(snapshot, context))
```

Thus far I have created this in `flow-typed/firebase-functions.js`

```
// @flow

declare module 'firebase-functions' {
  declare class firestore {
    static document(path: string): void;
  }
}
```

I am now stuck on `.onCreate(` part that is chained from document, flow doesn't allow me to extend `document` not `static document.opnCreate` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

In your flow-typed library code you are telling Flow that the `document` function returns void.

Then your application code you are using the results of that function, that you previously declared as void. I suspect this is why the compiler is complaining: calling `onCreate` on a null object doesn't work (or at least factor into the type system).

What happens if you do this: `static document(path: string): firestore`. Because that's (approximately: I don't know Firebase) what's happening here.

You will of course now need to declare function `onCreate`.

It's also worth noting that, for Javascript modules like firebase, that you don't need to write the flowtyped declarations yourself (unless you want/need to). `flow-typed install firebase@5.x.x` should install a community created (or generated) flowtyped file for you